# Windows 7, Python script to use command to access megawarc web archive file,

Tags: windows, python

I've found myself having to use a Python script to access a web archive.

What I have is a 'megawarc' web archive file from `http://archive.org/details/archiveteam-fanfiction-warc-11`. I need to un-megawarc this, using the Python script found at https://github.com/alard/megawarc.

I'm trying to run the `restore` command, and I have the three files needed (FILE.warc.gz, FILE.tar, and FILE.json.gz) from the first link.

I have both Python 2.7 and 3.3 installed.

*Update:*

I've ran both this method:

`python megawarc restore FILE`

And this method:

> Make sure you have the files `megawarc` and `ordereddict.py` in the same
>   directory, with the files you want to convert. Rename the file
>   `megawarc` to `megawarc.py` Open a Python console in this directory
>
> Type the following code (line by line) :
>
> `import sys`
>
> `sys.argv = ['megawarc','restore','FILE']`
>
> `import megawarc`

megawarc.main()using python 2.7, and this is what I get..

> `c:\Python27>python megawarc restore FILE`
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "megawarc", line 563, in
>    main()
>
> File "megawarc", line 552, in main mwr.process()
>
> File "megawarc", line 460, in process self.process_entry(entry,
>   tar_out)
>
> File "megawarc", line 478, in process_entry
>   entry["target"]["offset"], entry["target" ["size"])
>
> File "megawarc", line 128, in copy_to_stream raise Exception("End of
>   file: %d bytes expected, but %d bytes read." % (buf_size, l))
>
> Exception: End of file: 4096 bytes expected, but 236 bytes read.

Is there something else I'm missing?

I have the following files all in `C:\python27`:

- `FILE.tar.megawarc.json.gz`
- `FILE.tar.megawarc.tar`
- `FILE.tar.megawarc.warc.gz`
- `megawarc`
- `ordereddict.py`

Is this some type of corrupt file error? Some type of buffer error?  Is there something I'm missing?